# Check if composite primary key doesn't exist in a different table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using sql server. Currently I have 2 tables. I want to check if the composite PK from table 1 is not contained in table 2.

I tried using this but unfortunately it does not work in sql server. In this case the PK is composed of id1 and id2.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_1 WHERE (id1, id2) NOT IN (SELECT id1, id2 FROM TABLE_2)
```

I have seen more complicated solutions to this as well but, as I am trying to generate these queries as part of a python program I was hoping for an easy solution like the 1-line above.

Comment: That's what foreign key constraints are for

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - And what if the OP is looking to check if the parent (primary key) has no children (foreign key)?

Comment: SQL Server does not support tuples on both sides of the `IN` clause; it can only compare scalar values.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't allow multiple fields in `IN`. Different databases have different SQL dialects. None offer more than basic SQL compliance. Some products add convenience features without caring about performance (MySQL is the most common example) others add them only when they can ensure they'll perform adequately. Adding a feature like this may not be worth it for a vendor when alternatives like `NOT EXISTS` are just as easy to write.

Comment: The SQL Server team probably gives this a low priority because the functionality is already available and this particular syntax isn't that common. To properly execute such query the database engine *must* rewrite it as a `WHERE NOT EXISTS`. The naïve way of generating all inner tuples and comparing them to all outer tuples wouldn't use any indexes, resulting in full table scans for both tables. A smart query optimizer on the other hand could take advantage of indexes on `id1, id2` and use normal join operations to find the common rows between the inner and outer queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use an `EXISTS()` check...

```
SELECT
  table_1.*
FROM
  table_1
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
      FROM table_2
     WHERE table_2.id1 = table_1.id1
       AND table_2.id2 = table_1.id2
  )
```

In terms of a query being a single line, I don't recommend single line queries.  As a principle code should be long and narrow, not short and wide, and column references should always be qualified *(such as with a table name or alias)*...

For example, your non-working query could be laid out as follows, and suddenly doesn't appear meaningfully shorter than a `NOT EXISTS()` based query *(while also being significantly more maintainable, and more friendly to diff tools, such as used by git, etc)*.

```
SELECT
  table_1.*
FROM
  table_1
WHERE
  (
    table_1.id1,
    table_1.id2
  )
  NOT IN
  (
    SELECT
      table_2.id1,
      table_2.id2
    FROM
      table_2
  )
```

I too generate SQL from python *(be it through an ORM or my own abstraction layer)*, and neat queries are no harder to generate than "short single line queries".